# Add link to attachment in external ERP

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, navision, dynamics-nav

We have an ERP where scanned documents are stored.

The link to a documents comes in the format `localhost:8080/doc/PONo=121212`

We would like this link to be dynamically used on Navision in a Purchase Order workflow. For example when the document is attached to the ERP using the PO No. **121212** and the same number is filled as a field in Navision, then a link with the format  `localhost:8080/doc/PONo={PONo}` should take you to the ERP; where {PONo} is selected from Navision.

Comment: So what is the problem then? What exactly you want Nav to do and what version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure that I understood your requirement. But from what if the goal is to Navigate from NAV to that external ERP it can be achieved.

Just create a text variable or read from a setup(if any) the general link to your ERP.
So you will get a link in the following format `localhost:8080/doc/PONo=%1`.
On validate of a required field or OnAction use STRSUBSTNO to substitute %1 with your PO number.
After the link is ready and updated you can use something like `HYPERLINK(STRSUBSTNO(LinkTxt,PurchaseHeader."External Document No."))` or whatever field contains the Document No. in your other ERP.